# Determine which list has the most number of minimum values across multiple lists

Tags: python

I have a folowing issue. I have two list of k elements. I need to decide where is more minimal values. 
ex. k=5

```
a=[100,1,2,105,3]
b=[99,7,8,0,0]
```

and I need to chose a because there is more minimal values on first k- positions which belong to a.

I tried to sort and compare the values on each positions, but for this case it doesn't work. I will be grateful for any imput.

Comment: What are you even talking about? What do you mean by "there is more minimal values on first k- positions which belong to a"? Matching the elements up pairwise, b has 3 smaller elements and a has two, so that's not it. The minimum element across both lists is 0, and all 0s are in b, so that's not it either. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: 3 the smallest elements belong to a... it is 1, 2,3 in b there is only 0 and 0 in k=5 the smallest elements in both lists

Comment: So, for the 5 smallest values across both lists, find out which list has more of them.

Comment: How should ties be handled? What would the result be if the 99 was another 3? What if the 99 and the 7 were both 3s?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty basic version of what you need to get you started. You can use this as a starting point to solve your actual problem.

The main ingredients here are the use of `heapq.nsmallest` and `collections.Counter`.

- The `nsmallest` function finds the `n` smallest numbers from a list (in this case, the union of `a` and `b` lists).
- The `Counter` makes it easier to figure out where those `n` smallest numbers came from.

First, call `nsmallest` to get a list of numbers, and convert it to a `Counter` object -

```
import heapq
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter(heapq.nsmallest(5, a + b))    
print(ctr)
Counter({0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Next, you can perform arithmetic on `Counter` object. So, to find the count of minimum values from `b`, subtract `Counter(a)` from `ctr`. Correspondingly, to get the count of minimum values from `a`, subtract the result obtained earlier from `5` (`n`).

```
counts = {'b' : sum((ctr - Counter(a)).values())}
counts['a'] = 5 - counts['b']

print(counts)
{'a': 3, 'b': 2}
```

`counts` tells you how many minimum values came from each list. Use this to determine the list with the maximum number of min values.